# Proof by contradiction in Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Ok, so my college book is the worst book ever and I can only survive from this site and youtube. Could someone please explain the answer below? I really do not understand the answer and to me there is not sufficient information for me to get the conclusion.

Question:

```
Prove that if n is an integer and 3n+2 is even, then n is
even using
.
.
.
b) a proof by contradiction.
```

Answer:

Suppose that $3n+2$ is even and that $n$ is odd. Since $3n+2$ is even, so is $3n$. If we add or subtract an odd number from an even number, we get an odd number, so $3n-n=2n$. But this is obviously not true.Therefore our supposition is wrong, and the proof by contradiction is complete.

Ok, so I understand I need to prove that the contradiction is wrong for the proof to be true. Hence, we try to prove that the results $3n+2$ is even and that $n$ is an odd number. But I do not understand what the process was to get there nor do I understand this line: "If we add subtract an odd number from an even number, we get an odd number, so $3n-n=2n$." Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand how a proof by contradiction is *actually* a proof? If so, I could write up a nice, detailed solution, but I wonder if the main issue is in understanding how proofs by contradiction work and are logically valid.

Comment: I understand how proof by contradiction works. Proof by contradiction means that if I prove that not p is false than p is true. I would greatly appreciate it if you wrote up a detailed solution. I have this bookmarked so I will be coming back and reading it frequently throughout the semester. thanks.

Comment: Since you have already accepted an answer, I do not want to provide a duplicate one. In the future, do not accept an answer until you are *fully* satisfied with it. I assume Johanna's answer truly addressed everything you were wondering about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea with a proof by contradiction is to start with something false: in this case assuming that $3n+2$ is even and $n$ is odd. Then we do only logically sound operations to what we start with. If you subtract $2$ from an even number, then the result is even, right? And if you subtract an odd number from an even number, you get an odd number. So we reach the conclusion that $2n$ is odd. But this is obviously false. $2$ times anything is even, so we have a contradiction. Hence what we started with has to be false, so $n$ is odd.

Does that make more sense? Let me know if you want me to clarify.

Comment: something clicked in my head when I read yours, but ALL the answers have helped me understand this. I appreciate it so much. I am about to live on this site now. Thanks!!

Comment: @Ducksauce88 I'm happy I could help :)

Comment: @SpamIAm Fixed it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The result you want to prove is of the form $P\to Q$. The proof by contradiction consists in getting a contradiction from $P$ and $\sim Q$.

The proof given is correct. When they say "If we add subtract an odd number from an even number, we get an odd number, so $3n-n=2n$", they mean that in general if you add *or* subtract an odd number from an even number, the result is odd (that's obvious), and *since* $3n-n=2n$ and $3n$ is even and $n$ is odd by hypothesis (that's $\sim Q$), $2n$ must be odd, which is a contradiction since any multiple of $2$ is even, not odd.

Answer (score 0):

(i) A proof my contradiction works by supposing what is to be proven is false and reaching a contradiction by that assumption.

(ii)
$$\underbrace{(2m+1)}_{\text{odd}} - \underbrace{(2n)}_{\text{even}} = \underbrace{(2(m -n) + 1)}_{\text{odd}} $$